# Flutter Firestore - To retrieve document snapshots belonging to only a certain set of ids and show that data on screen

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-futurebuilder

I am passing my constructor list of Firestore Document Ids and I want to retrieve and show data belonging to those ids only in my 'LinksData' collection.

So basically I want to retrieve the Document snapshot of all documents belonging to id's that are in another list of mine (which I am passing in the constructor).

I could think of two methods :

1. Using StreamBuilder, but according to what i know, with this i will either get all the documents snapshots in my collection or just one.
2. Using Future Builder, i made this following function but when i use it , it shows the following error

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform
```

**How can i do this? I don't want to retrieve all the documents using stream builder, because that would affect my daily reads.**

Here is the code of how i tried using FutureBuilder.

```
FutureBuilder<List<LinkCards>>(
                future: generateList(widget.linksDataIds),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Center(child: Text('Oops! Some Error Occurred!'));
                  } else {
                    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                    }
                    return GridView.builder(
                        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                          maxCrossAxisExtent: 220,
                          mainAxisSpacing: 12.0,
                        ),
                        itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return snapshot.data![index];
                        });
                  }
                },
              )
```

Here is my Future fucntion

```
  Future<List<LinkCards>> generateList(List<dynamic> listLinksDataId) async {
    FirebaseFirestore fireStore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    List<LinkCards> listCards = [];

    listLinksDataId.forEach((linkDataId) async {
      print(linkDataId);

      await fireStore
          .collection('LinksData')
          .doc(linkDataId)
          .get()
          .then((value) => {
                listCards.add(LinkCards(
                  link: value.get('link'),
                  linkTitle: value.get('title'),
                  linkImage: value.get('image'),
                  relatedCategories: value.get('categories'),
                  platform: value.get('platform'),
                ))
              });
    });
    return listCards;
  }
```

Here is an image of how my database is structured : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3E7dB.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your replies, but i found a solution by modifying my database a little bit.
In 'LinksData' collection, I put a field (type array) which will contain all the categories. Then i used the StreamBuilder instead like this :

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection('LinksData')
                    .where('categories', arrayContains: widget.categoryName)
                    .snapshots(),

                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Center(child: Text('${snapshot.error}'));
                  } else {
                    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                    }
                    return GridView.builder(
                        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                          maxCrossAxisExtent: 220,
                          mainAxisSpacing: 12.0,
                        ),
                        itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return LinkCards(
                              linkImage: snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('image'),
                              linkTitle: snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('name'),
                              link: snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('link'),
                              relatedCategories: snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('categories'),
                              platform: snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('platform'));
                        });
                  }
                },
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

This how your function should ideally look like.
Give it a try, and hopefully it will work.

```
Future<List<LinkCards>> generateList(List<dynamic> listLinksDataId) async {
    FirebaseFirestore fireStore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    List<LinkCards> listCards = [];
    for(int i=0; i<listLinksDataId.length;i++){

       final firestoreResult = await fireStore
          .collection('LinksData')
          .doc(linkDataId)
          .get();
       listCards.add(
        link: firestoreResult.data()["link"],
        linkTitle: firestoreResult.data()["title"],
        linkImage: firestoreResult.data()["image"],
        relatedCategories: firestoreResult.data()["categories"],
        platform: firestoreResult.data()["platform"],
       );

    }
    return listCards;
  }
```

This is the approach I usually go for, and hopefully will be useful for you too.

Comment: With this, control goes into snapshot.hasError , and on further printing firestoreResult.data()["link"], it still gives null., even though it is there in the database.

Comment: The error is because this function doesn't know what `linkDataId` is. In the original question it was from the `forEach` loop but in this one with the regular for loop `linkDataId` doesn't exist at all.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you pretty close. It's a simplified example that I can reproduce that just uses a list of Strings.

```
Future<List<String>> generateList(List<String> listLinksDataId) async {
    List<String> listCards = [];
    final collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('LinksData');
    for (String docId in listLinksDataId) {
      final snapshot = await collection.doc(docId).get(); 

     // snapshot is the document snapshot whose id 
     // matches the index in the list you're passing in

      final linksData = snapshot['linksData']; // list of ids in linksData field

      for (var i = 0; i < linksData.length; i++) { // looping through list
        final field = linksData[i];
        listCards.add(field);
      }
    }
    return listCards;
  }
```

This will at the very least return all of the id's in the `linksData` field only in the documents that match an index of the list you pass in.

You should be able to setup a quick test page and a `FutureBuilder<ListString>>` and pass in this method as the `Future`.

Return a `ListView` that just displays text widgets and you'll see all the ids that you want.

```
Expanded(
   child: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
         Text(snapshot.data![index])),
   );
```

Then you can modify from there to fully populate your `LinkCard`.